# MySQL cannot recognise with time zone: Australia/Eucla (GMT+08:45)

Tags: mysql, timezone

I have a client in the time zone Australia/Eucla (GMT+08:45). PHP recognises this timezone fine but when I try to convert a date using MySQL, I get NULL returned. I store all my dates in GMT+00:00 time and then convert them.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT  CONVERT_TZ( '2013-05-04 23:30:00' , '+00:00', '+08:75')
    -> NULL
```

And if I use the timezone names:

```
SELECT  CONVERT_TZ( '2013-05-04 23:30:00' , 'UTC', 'Australia/Eucla')
    -> NULL
```

The MySQL on my server is **5.0.96-community-log - MySQL Community Edition (GPL)**.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update MySQL's timezone table. Assuming this zone is in your system's `zoneinfo` file, you can use the `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` command to update it. You can find details in the MySQL documentation [MySQL Server Time Zone Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time-zone-support.html)

If you want to see what the command does, redirect the output to a file first:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo > zones.sql
```

and look at the zones.sql file. Once you're satisfied, you can execute it with:

```
mysql -u root -p < zones.sql
```

Comment: OK so it looks like I do have a `zoneinfo` file. In the following command `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql`, would I replace the second instance of `mysql` with the database name? Or do I leave it as is?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. I was just looking at my servers `mysql` table and I presume that's what the second `mysql` was for? Currently all the `time_zone*` tables in my `mysql` database are empty. So when I run that command, it will populate these? Me being a bit of a noob, could this update stuff anything up or is it quite safe? Appreciate your help

Comment: It should be safe, especially since your tables are all empty right now. If you're paranoid, you can do `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo > zones.sql` and then examine the zones.sql file to see what queries it will run. Then do `mysql -u root mysql < zones.sql`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yep, always paranoid when I haven't done some before and have a lot of users who will have a lot of issues if I mess this up :) Quick question. If the tables are all empty right now, where would it be pulling the time zone data from? I'm currently on a WHM/Cpanel server.

Answer (score 0):

You must populate the mysql time_zone tables manually since they are empty by default.

```
shell> mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql
```

Once loaded you can run for example:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ( order_time,  'Australia/Melbourne',  'Australia/Perth' ) AS converted_time
FROM orders
```